# Copying feature layers

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer

I am trying to copy feature layers using the following code, but get no results. Can anyone help me understand why the code does not work?

```
import os
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.workspace = ws = 'C:\\WorkSpace\\sahie_saipe\\sahie_saipe.gdb'
dictionary_Layer = {'co06_Layer':'co06', 'co07_Layer':'co07', 'cnty08_Layer':'co08', 'co09_Layer':'co09', 'co10_Layer':'co10', 'co11_Layer':'co11', 'co12_Layer':'co12', 'st_Select':'state'}
for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if layer in dictionary_Layer:
        old = os.path.join(ws, layer)
        new = os.path.join(ws, dictionary_Layer[layer])
        try:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(old,new,"")
            print 'copy %s to %s' %(layer, dictionary_Layer[layer])
        except:
            print 'Could not copy %s'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **arcpy.mapping.ListLayers** try using **arcpy.ListFeatureClasses**.  It will go off of the workspace, which you are already setting, and I have found it pretty easy to use.

See more information [HERE](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001n000000)

Answer (score 0):

If this is the full code then I believe the code is failing as where do you specify the `mxd` variable? The [ListLayers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ListLayers/00s30000002n000000/) function takes a map document object.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have corrected the 'mxd' issue and still get no results!